# StoreGeneratedPattern and SaveChanges() throw Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql-9.1

If i use `StoreGeneratedPattern="None"` then SaveChanges() throws an Exception. It tries to save an object admin with `ID=0`. It does the same for all other objects. The `ID` is always 0. If i use  `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` an Exception is thrown again:

```
A null store-generated value was returned for a non-nullable member 'AdminId'
```

I have this column in my Table:

```
adminid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('admin.seq_admin'::regclass)
```

**EDIT** Is nextval the right command for the autoincrement? Is there `IDENTITY` in postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with nextval is the right command for autoincrement.
I had the same problem with postgresql, and tired manny different settigns either in ef and pgsql, but the problem gone when I recreated the table and somehow new sequence with 1 at the end (tasktasktitleid_seq1) automatically generated.

EDIT: I got the same problem again so what that's what I did:
 1. deleted Id from table.
 2. Created new colum of type big serial
 3. Opened table properties and added new primary key in constraints tab. 
After I saved the table, I got my default value for id a new auto-generated sequence and from then on my saves that table flawless..ly